# How to fix Layoutinflator not found error?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display a custom list  .I am passing a string array to the class customAdapter. when I try to access the getLayoutInflater it is not being recognized? How can I solve this issue

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> descriptions;
     public CustomAdapter(final ArrayList<String> description) {
         descriptions=description;    
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return descriptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {    
       view=getLayotInflater(R.layout.rowcourses,null);   
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here, change this constructor

```
private Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, final ArrayList<String> description) {
         descriptions=description;  
         context = context;  
    }
```

and modify this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {  
   // so you would require an Inflater service which will load/inflate the layout, and to use service,
   // you need to have access to context, which you can get it from the constructor by passing it from your host class.

     LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

              View aView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowcourses, parent,false);
  // once you load the view, you need to return that, in your case you were returning null   
                return aView;
            }
```

Comment: while this answer may work, can you explain your answer for the OP? this can help him understand both what he did wrong and your answer

Comment: what should I pass when I create an object of class custom adapter CustomAdapter a=new CustomAdapter(Description); gives error.

Comment: @Sheildboy, if you are calling from activity, CustomAdapter a=new CustomAdapter(this, Description); and from fragment CustomAdapter a=new CustomAdapter(getContext(), Description);

Comment: @notTdar but the constructor takes two argument